# Spaces losing Dock's "Assign To" option selection after restart

Tags: dock, monterey, spaces

I make use of spaces and there are several apps that I like to make available in all spaces. To do so, you right click on the app's icon in the dock and select **Options** > **Assign To** > **All Desktops**:

[image: Options > Assign To > All Desktops]

This works fine until the computer restarts. After a restart, **All Desktops** will be checked but the app will in fact be assigned to a particular desktop — I haven't been able to figure out how it picks which desktop to assign it to.

The workaround is to select another option like **None** and then select **All Desktops** again, but having to do this for several apps every time the computer restarts is a chore.

Some [similar problems](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8384830) have suggested unchecking **Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use** in the **Mission Control** preference pane, but I've already got that unchecked:

[image]

How do I get it to retain the option selected after a restart?

I'm using macOS Monterey 12.6.

Comment: I've had odd issues like [but not identical to] this which were fixed by re-launching the Dock itself. In Terminal, just `killall Dock` should do it. It should auto-relaunch.

Comment: Unfortunately no change after using `killall Dock`. The issue continued after the next restart.

Comment: All I can guess is it may be caused by something 3rd party that runs from startup. The usual trick is to see if you create a new admin account, that is affected too. After that it gets down to a messy set of uninstalls of anything you can think of that you might have installed just before it first happened; or clean instal without migration… all very inconvenient & to avoid if you can.